# pagenumbering basic alph and subpages arabic

Tags: page-numbering

For my master thesis I want a clean looking pagenumbering for the non-content pages.
"
For example the Glossary should start on Page "C" (only "C" as entry in the toc) but if it is more than one Page long the additional pages should be numbered "C1","C2",...

Yet I have included a `\pagenumbering{Alph}` which makes the non-content pages counted with Alpha numeric letters but my glossary, acronyms, references and appendix pages are quite much and there are several letters "skipped" in the toc... (Glossaries occupies space from C to H)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this before the glossary.

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{%
    C%
    \ifnum\value{page}>0\relax
        \arabic{page}%
    \fi}
\setcounter{page}{0}
```

If you want the non-content pages marked continuously (A, B, B1, C, ...), you can automize it with

```
\newcounter{mainpage}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{%
    \Alph{mainpage}%
    \ifnum\value{page}>1\relax
        \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
        \arabic{page}%
        \addtocounter{page}{1}%
    \fi}
\newcommand{\switchpage}{%
    \stepcounter{mainpage}%
    \setcounter{page}{1}}
```

and use `\switchpage` *after* each new main page (including the first) has started. Note that this code should be added *after* the last content page.

---

A negative side with this numbering scheme is that odd pagenumbers indicate left-hand pages instead of right-hand, which is standard. There is unfortunally no way to combine the three requirements of using this scheme, starting chapters  on right-hand pages, and having odd numbers indicate right-hand pages.

Comment: Well that works but has some bugs. The very first page after the content (added the second code sample between content and acronyms) is started with "1" second page is "A". Last Page is "B" and references (which comes right after acronyms) starts with "B1" and ends with "C"

Comment: You're right. It works if you instead add `\switchpage` after `\chapter` (or whatever you are using). Btw, I realized that this messed with the formatting of twosided layouts, like the book class, so I edited the code to fix the problem as much as possible.